# How can I statically assert that two fields in different third-party libraries are the same?

Tags: c++

If I have something like:

```cpp
// library 1:

struct A
{
    struct B
    {
        std::map<std::string, int> LookupTable;
    };

    B b;
};

// library 2:
struct C
{
    std::map<std::string, int> LookupTable;
};
```

How could one write something akin to the following, but that actually works?

```cpp
// 1
static_assert(typeof(A::B::LookupTable) == typeof(C::LookupTable));

// 2
static_assert(typeof(A::B::LookupTable) == typeof(map<std::string, int>));

// 3
A a;
static_assert(typeof(a.x) == typeof(map<std::string, int>));
```

The `typeof` and `typeid` operators obviously don't suit the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `decltype` instead of `typeof`, and `std::is_same_v` instead of `==`:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(A::B::LookupTable), decltype(C::LookupTable)>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(C::LookupTable), std::map<std::string, int>>);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4Tvb7Edce)

Comment: Yep, that original answer I wrote was nonsense. Deleted.